# In Ubuntu Desktop my Arduino Uno shows up as /dev/ttyACM0 .... where is it in android?

Tags: usb, nexus-5, linux, command-line, motorola-droid-4

When I connect an Arduino Uno via USB to my Linux Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, the arduino shows up as /dev/ttyACM0 .... When I connect it via usb to an android phone the device is powered and recognized in Android apps, but I can't seem to find it when i look in a terminal emulator at the /dev folder. When I browse android's directory structure using terminal, where can I find the analogous device?

Further elaboration: 
On the desktop I can access the USB arduino device with no trouble, using

screen /dev/ttyACM0

or I can even pipe characters to it directly such as:

echo -n w > /dev/ttyACM0

On the android device, there are no tty* devices in that folder at all.

Someone I know recommended I install a full linux distro on top of android, GNUroot Debian, and maybe it would be there. I did this on both an LG Nexus 5 with android 6.0 as well as a Moto Droid 4 with Android 4.1.2, in hopes that those familiar devices /dev/ttyACM would show up, but they didn't.

Is there any similiar thing to /dev/ttyACM0 in android?

Thank you!

android-controlled-robot

Comment: Both devices don't natively support OTG, so naturally no USB device will be powered on or recognized.

Comment: thank you for your comment! sorry if i didn't clarify, with the Nexus 5 the arduino does successfully get power from the micro usb, and in various usb apps like droidterm, a hyperterminal android app, i can control the arduino from the app.   so that part is solved, at least on the nexus. accessing it from the bash terminal is the thing i can't seem to figure out.  for the droid 4, i suppose i should look at somehow how to add otg?